# In reactjs console.log is not working using onSubmit for form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. Please advise why the console.log() is not showing on the console after submitting the form.

In handleSubmit function `e.preventDefault()` and `this.setState({ errors })` is executing properly but not console log.

Please advise what I am doing wrong in below code.

*react version: 16.14.0
Windows OS*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Input from "./common/input";

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      account: {
        username: "",
        password: "",
      },
      errors: {},
    };
  }

  handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    const account = { ...this.state.account };
    account[input.name] = input.value;
    this.setState({ account: account });
  };

  validate = () => {
    const errors = {};

    const { account } = this.state;
    if (account.username.trim() === "")
      errors.username = "Username is required";
    if (account.password.trim() === "")
      errors.password = "Password is required";

    return Object.keys(errors).length === 0 ? null : errors;
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    const errors = this.validate();
    console.log(errors);    // If errors it is not showing anything on console
    this.setState({ errors });
    if (errors) return;
    console.log("Submitted");  // if no errors this message should show on console but its not
  };

  render() {
    const { account } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>LoginForm</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Input
            name="username"
            value={account.username}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            Label="Username"
          />
          <Input
            name="password"
            value={account.password}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            Label="Password"
          />
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default LoginForm;
```

**Edit:**
I used this exact same code in another application and its working.
Please advise also on any specific app settings need to look for?

*code editor: Visual Studio*
*Browser: Chrome*

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide your code in  a https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: Check your browser console for log filters. You may have accidentally applied it.

Comment: I have run this code in a sandbox & it is working perfectly. Check if your custom Input components are working correctly.